# What is the syntax for .attr in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
$("#left").attr("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-right");
```

which changes the glyphicon from a left to a right arrow, and this works just fine, but now I want to change a picture, still using the .attr function. But instead of using

```
.attr("CLASS".....)
```

I want to use the id selector. I can't seem to get the right syntax for this. Here is what I have right now:

```
$(".overlay").click(function(){
var id = "image"+$(this).attr('id');
console.log(id);
return id;
})
$("#big").attr('id', "#"+id);
```

Answer (score 1):

In much the same way your class attribute takes two space-separated class names instead of two class *selectors* (i.e. `glyphicon glyphicon-right`, not `.glyphicon.glyphicon-right`), your id attribute takes an ID, not an ID *selector*. You don't need the leading `#`:

```
$("#big").attr('id', id);
```

And this line should be at the end of your click handler, not outside it. The return statement is inappropriate and should be removed:

```
$(".overlay").click(function(){
  var id = "image"+$(this).attr('id');
  console.log(id);
  $("#big").attr('id', id);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> use $('#yourImageId').attr('src','image url here')

```js
$(document).on('click','#mybtn',function(){
 
 $('#myimg').attr('src','https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504519733529-35b35d10eee2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="myimg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499949059451-9a1119d4e912" height="200" width="200"/>
<button id="mybtn" type="button">Change Image</button>
```